# Stuck on a program in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing an assignment for school and I just can't get past the final hurdle. I've only been doing coding for about 2 weeks and this is beyond me on how to fix. I am hoping someone here can help me in any way possible.

We need to make an Eiffel Tower with Python that has an adjustable size, and we cannot use any statements we haven't learned. The only ones I know at the moment are the math operators, if, print, newlines, and basic formatting.

Here are the basics of my assignment and how I've gone about it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kz5c.jpg

here is my code in python:

```
size = int(input('Enter Eiffel Tower Size:\n'))

print(' ' * ((size * 2) + (size - 1)) + '$')

print(((' ' * (size  * 3 - 2)) + '|Z|' + '\n') * int(size * 1.5), end='')

print(' ' * ((size * 3) - (size + 2)) + '/' + 'Z' * (size * 2 + 1) + '\\')

print(' ' * ((size * 3) - (size + 2)) + 'H' + ' ' * (size * 2 + 1) + 'H')

print(' ' * ((size * 3) - (size + 2)) + 'H' + ' ' * (size * 2 + 1) + 'H')

print(' ' * (size - 2) + '/' + '%' * (size * 4 +1) + '\\')

print((' ' * (size - 3) + '##' + ' ' * (size * 4 + 1) + '##' + '\n') * int(size // 1.5), end='')

print((' ' * (size - 4) + '##' + ' ' * (size * 4 + 1) + '  ##' + '\n') * int(size // 1.5))
```

Any number 4 or less causes my last line to become broken, and the program to print incorrectly. I'm at my wits end trying to figure this out and I don't know what else to try.

Comment: For `size<=3`, `(size - 4)` is negative. You cannot multiply a string by a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the tower off the edge of the console. Add more space on the left for each print statement:

```
size = 2

print(' ' * (size + (size * 2) + (size - 1)) + '$')
print(((' ' * (size + size  * 3 - 2)) + '|Z|' + '\n') * int(size * 1.5), end='')
print(' ' * (size + (size * 3) - (size + 2)) + '/' + 'Z' * (size * 2 + 1) + '\\')
print(' ' * (size + (size * 3) - (size + 2)) + 'H' + ' ' * (size * 2 + 1) + 'H')
print(' ' * (size + (size * 3) - (size + 2)) + 'H' + ' ' * (size * 2 + 1) + 'H')
print(' ' * (size + size - 2) + '/' + '%' * (size * 4 +1) + '\\')
print((' ' * (size + size - 3) + '##' + ' ' * (size * 4 + 1) + '##' + '\n') * int(size // 1.5), end='')
print((' ' * (size + size - 4) + '##' + ' ' * (size * 4 + 1) + '  ##' + '\n') * int(size // 1.5))
```

Output

```
       $
      |Z|
      |Z|
      |Z|
    /ZZZZZ\
    H     H
    H     H
  /%%%%%%%%%\
 ##         ##
##           ##
```